# How can I change the grammar in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

in my query

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT p_index,m_id,DATE_FORMAT(trdDtTm, '%Y%m%d') as trdDtTm FROM ".$this->itemsTable." WHERE m_id = 2");$stmt->bind_param("i", $this->m_id);
```

result

```
{"items":[{"p_index":7,"m_id":"2","trdDtTm":"20220203"}}
```

However, if you search after changing the trdDtTm format, the results will not come out. How do I fix it?

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT p_index,m_id,DATE_FORMAT(trdDtTm, '%Y%m%d') as trdDtTm FROM ".$this->itemsTable." WHERE m_id = 2 and trdDtTm = 20220203"); 
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $this->m_id, $this->trdDtTm);
```

no items.. how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trdDtTm` is a datetime column.

```
WHERE trdDtTm = 20220203
```

compares a datetime with a number hence. This makes hardly sense. Maybe you hope for the DBMS to magically match the two, but you shouldn't. Compare with a date literal instead:

```
WHERE trdDtTm = DATE '2022-02-03'
```

And if you want to find all rows on that date regardless of the time (the above only finds midnight, as `DATE '2022-02-03'` is considered equal to `TIMESTAMP '2022-02-03 00:00:00'`), do:

```
WHERE trdDtTm >= DATE '2022-02-03' AND trdDtTm < DATE '2022-02-04'
```

Comment: I think the OP's question was that he changed the date format in the select list and then filtered using the new date format in the where clause. However, column aliases only kick in the having clause, so trdttm in the where clause still refers to the original column, not its aliased version.

Comment: @Shadow yes. right. so.. how to change query? answer please..

Comment: @Shadow: Ah, I see. Thank you for clarifying this. 전준휘, You should better not use the same name for the alias as for the column. Had you used another alias, say `date_without_time` and used `WHERE date_without_time= 20220203`, then you'd have gotten an error telling you that you cannot access an alias name given in a select clause in your where clause, because the latter happens before the former. And as your new trdDtTm is a string, why are you comparing it with a number 20220203 and not a string '20220203'? Anyway, my where clause should work for you. The other option would be  subquery.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The reason why it is not a string is that it only compares numbers after changing the format.

Comment: @전준휘 I would go with the proposed solution in this question. I only made a comment because I thought the explanation part of the answer was missing a point. Btw, your new column is **not** a number! It is a string that looks like a number!